# CSS Flexbox image overflow

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, overflow

After trying various solutions found on here, and other places on the internet/youtube, I still can't seem to figure out why the images in a flexbox are overflowing.
What am I missing/doing wrong?

I simplified a code for example:

Link Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Sjoeff/pen/oNqVgqW

HTML:

```
<html>  
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="section1">
        <p>This a section of the website</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section2">
        <div class="gal-wrapper">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" />
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" />
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" />
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" />
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" />
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section3">
        <p>This a section of the website</p>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.section2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.gal-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.gal-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* display: flex ?*/
  /* flex: 1; ?*/
}

.section3 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The overflow happens because the height of `section2` is 100vh, which is smaller than the space the actual flex layout needs: 2 rows of 350x350 pictures, resulting in 700px vertically. If you would like to prevent this overflow, remove the 100vh from `section2`'s CSS.

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Great, you're welcome! You can accept this answer as the solution so it'll be clear for future readers:)